# Describe all real-valued functions which are analytic on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

This is a homework question, so if I am wrong please do not explicitly give me the answer.

***Question:*** Describe all real-valued functions which are analytic on $\mathbb{C}$.

***My Answer:*** Given that we are describing all real-valued functions, this implies that $iv(x,y)=0$ for the equation $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. Thus, $u_x=v_y=0$ and $u_y=-v_x=0$.

Am I missing anything? This answer seems too easy, but I am having a hard time wrapping my head around a real-valued function being analytic with the Cauchy-Riemann equations equaling zero.

Comment: otherwise, you can say that if $f(z)$ is analytic and non constant then $f(z_0+z) = f(z_0) + C z^n + \mathcal{O}(|z|^{n+1})$ (where $C = f^{(n)}(z_0)/n!$ is the first derivative non vanishing at $z_0$) *so it can't be real valued*

Comment: No, you're not missing anything. Given that the partial derivatives are zero, what functions satisfy these requirements?

Comment: @Mark : It would just be any function where $u_x=u_y=v_x=v_y=0$, correct? Or am I missing what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, but you can explicitly describe such functions.

Comment: It would just be a function that is a constant, right?

Comment: Do you have the open mapping theorem? This spills all of the beans.

Comment: That's an interesting way of doing it @user1952009, I will have to play around with bit. Thank you for your help.

Comment: We have not covered that yet @ncmathsadist. We have covered the very basics on the topology of $\mathbb{C}$. However, looking at the definition in Wikipedia, it doesn't seem like it would require much extra though given what I already know.

Comment: @zhw All I'm trying to say is that given what the question asks for, this implies that $iv(x,y)=0$. Probably poorly worded on my part.

Comment: Look at the Cauchy-Riemann equations.